# Checking odd numbers python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm stuck on this question for checking odd numbers, with for loop method

I've been given part of this code to produce odd numbers only

```
def get_odds(items):

    new_list = []

    return new_list
```

If anyone can help, that would be great - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
def get_odds(items):
    new_list = [item for item in items if item % 2 == 1]
    return new_list
```

**Edit**: If you *have to* use a `for` loop, you can write something in the lines of:

```
def get_odds(items):
    new_list = []
    for item in items:
        if item % 2 == 1:
            new_list.append(item)
    return new_list
```

As you will see, this is just a longer way of writing the first solution.

Comment: Or possibly generator expression.

Comment: Thanks Selcuk, but how do I express it?

Comment: @GerasimovMikhail: Why? The function has to return a list.

Comment: @PM2Ring, in most cases we don't need list, we need something iterable. OP might not know what generators are and why it's better to prefer them over lists.

Comment: @GerasimovMikhail Sure, generators are often better than lists. But I suspect this is homework and the OP _has to_ return a list, as specified in the question.

Comment: @jakuv what you mean by word "express"? After you created function, you can call it: `res = get_odds([1, 2, 3, 4])` and, for example, print result: `print res`.

Comment: Thanks @Selcuk! This works well - appreciate you taking the time to help with this

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
 for a in range(10000):
       if a%2==1:
         new_list.append(a)
```

I am sure there are better algorithms but it is early and I have not had an coffee yet :)

Comment: Thanks Tim, but I can't seem to get it to work with the odds.

Comment: This answer does not take the argument (`items`) into account either.

Comment: As you all seem to be wanting your homework done why not try

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_odds(items):

    new_list = []    ###create an empty container to store odd no.s when passed into it
    for item in items:   ### loop over your items (a list probably)
        if item%2 != 0:  ####here u will get odd numbers(Yes ==1 also works)
           new_list.append(item)
    return new_list
```

Note: though List comprehension are more pythonic way, but a for loop is easy to understand logic.

Comment: Thanks @Satya! For loop is the method!

Answer (score 0):

```
l = lambda(y) : [i for i in xrange(y) if i%2!=0]
print l(1000)
```

Or simply

```
odd_list = [i for i in xrange(1000) if i%2!=0]
```

Comment: Thanks @PradyJord, this works! But for loop is the preferred method I should have put